# TightVNC External Remote Access Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, networking, router, vnc, raspberry-pi

I am running into some trouble accessing my Raspberry Pi (running Raspbian) from my WAN IP.

- TightVNCserver is installed and running on port `5901` on the Raspberry Pi.
- Port forwarding is enabled on my router/switch from `5900` to `5901` going to the Raspberry Pi’s internal address.
- If using the internal `192.x.x.x` address the Raspberry Pi is accessible.
- When attempting to access the Raspberry Pi from my external WAN with port 5901 specified I receive “connection refused.”
- Ran a `nmap -sV` scan to verify port `5901` is open on the Raspberry Pi.
- Temporarily disabled my router’s firewall to see if it was blocking anything and got the same results.

Any thoughts?

Comment: first use canyouseeme.org to confirm that the NAT rule is working correctly. Also note that VNC is not a safe protocol to expose externally, and it is likely that your ISP is blocking 5900-5910 so consider using a differant port. All in all, it is best to tunnel VNC over SSH if you want to expose it externally.  http://www.hertaville.com/2012/09/27/raspbian-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @FrankThomas probably right that VNC isn't that safe externally i'm not sure what protocol is so perhaps any should be wrapped in SSH.. But do you have a source for that re VNC not being safe?

Comment: @barlop, I can only suggest you google so that the information does not become outdated, but it comes down to these primary concerns. First, in the generic VNC supports no connection encryption, so the stream can be copied and viewed by users on intermediary networks. Some specific VNC implementations (Ultra for instance) can encrypt the stream if the client and server are paired, but there are a host of limitations. Second, for legacy reasons most VNC server implementations limit passwords to 8-characters, and don't like specials. this is also vendor dependent.

Comment: @barlop, there are some protocols that are safe, like TeamViewer, and RDP can be secured, but Indeed, most LAN protocols should be run either through an SSH gateway, or a strong VPN (preferably L2TP/IPSec, and preferably not SSL).

Comment: @FrankThomas When you say RDP "can be secured" (I see you are probably getting at RDPS, so, it using TLS). You say TeamViewer is secure(I guess you mean it uses TLS).

Comment: If you're trying to use your WAN address from inside you LAN, your router may not support that (many don't).  Try accessing it via the WAN address from another computer on the WAN/Internet.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

- Port forwarding [..] on my router/switch from `5900` to `5901`
- attempting to access [..] from my external WAN with port `5901`

If this is correct, you’re trying to access a port (`5901`) that you've not told your router to forward (you told it to forward connections to **5900** on the outside to `5901` on the Raspberry Pi).

I’m not sure why you forwarded `5900` to `5901`, but if that is the case you'll want to try and connect to `5900` from the outside. Alternatively, map `5901` to `5901` for a less confusing setup.